# How to use margins in CSS Firefox animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation:

```
@media (max-width: 768px). 
{.fptext {color:white; 
font-weight: bolder; 
position: relative; bottom: 
450px; font-size: 0px; 
left: 100px; text-size- 
adjust:none;}}



@media (max-width: 768px). 
{.fptext {animation: 
fadeout 
30s ease 
forwards;animation-delay: 
0s;padding:0px;-moz- 
animation:fadeout 30s ease 
forwards 0s infinite
}}

@keyframes fadeout{
from {font-size: 0px;} to 
{font-size: 45px;}}

@media(max-width: 768px) 
{.textwidget>.fatext{
animation: bigger 30s ease 
forwards;animation-delay: 
0s;; 
position:relative;font- 
size: 15px; 
color:#43ff0a;bottom: 
1700px; font- 
weight:bolder;padding: 
0px;background-  
color:blue;display:
block;margin-bottom: 
-1750px
}} 

@keyframes bigger 
{from{font-size: 0px} to 
{font-size: 18px;}}

@media (max-width:768px). 
{.fptext {margin-top: 
-325px; z-index:7; 
color:#43ff0a; margin-left: 
-200px; 
}}

@media(max-width: 768px). 
{.black{animation: 
blacktext 30s ease 
forwards;animation-delay: 
0s;; 
position:relative;font- 
size: 15px; 
color:#000;bottom: 737px; 
font-weight:bolder;padding: 
0px;background-  
color:transparent;displa
y:block;z-index: 20; 
right:22px;


}} 

@keyframes blacktext 
{from{font-size: 0px} to 
{font-size: 45px;}}

<div class="fatext">text 
text></div>
<div class="fptext">text 
text></div>
<div class="black">text 
text></div>
```

As you can see, I've used `bottom` and `margin-bottom,` with position relative, and margin structure is generally quite complex. Chrome understands this, Firefox doesn't. Is there some kind of issue with margins in Firefox because it  sends element `fatext` and `black` below where it should be, whereas Chrome, and every other browser, positions it where I want it?

Page [here](https://4309.co.uk) mobile

Comment: Protip: [Never link just the word "here"](http://stephanieleary.com/2015/05/why-click-here-is-a-terrible-link-and-what-to-write-instead/)

Comment: Some formatting would really help the readability of your code. Remember that good code is also readable by humans :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.