# Can I relate an element to a specific browser with CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

Basically I have an animation that, no matter what I did, did not work in Firefox. So i decided to create an animation to work solely in, and tailored solely for, firefox.

```
@media (max-width: 768px). 
{.fptext {-moz- 
animation:moz 
30s ease forwards
}}

@keyframes moz{
from {font-size: 0px;} to 
{font-size: 1px;}}

<div class="fptext"></div>
```

The problem comes in positioning the element. Any positioning would effect other browsers. It's easy to do defining just the animation because I have selector `-moz-animation`, but is there a way of defining width, height, margin etc just for Firefox?

Comment: Why the animation doesn't work on firefox? Please share a working example of that animation so we can help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830383/how-to-use-margins-in-css-firefox-animations

Comment: What about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/953491/4534916

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: Thanks dudes I'll check it out....